# "Too many positional arguments: 2 excepted, but 3 found. try removing the extra arguments" . please help me:(

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
body:Container(
        //child: IndexedStack(
          //index: _selectedIndex,
          //children: _items
        //)//_items.elementAt(_index),
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.25,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: IndexedStack(
          index: _selectedIndex,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                minimumSize: const
                Size.fromHeight(50)
              ),
              child: Text('SUBUH'),
              onPressed: (){
                Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => halamansubuh(
                  )
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      minimumSize: const
                      Size.fromHeight(100)
                  ),
                    child: Text('ZUHUR'),
                    onPressed: (){
                      Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => halamanzuhur(title: 'halamanzuhur', desc: 'halamanzuhur',
                        
                        )
                        ));
                    }
                  ),
                  );
              }
            )
```

Comment: Would you precisely point out which segment of the code has the issue you've mentioned?

Comment: ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      minimumSize: const
                      Size.fromHeight(100)
                  ),
                    child: Text('ZUHUR'),
                    onPressed: (){
                      Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => halamanzuhur(title: 'halamanzuhur', desc: 'halamanzuhur',
                        
                        )
                        ));
                    }
                  ),

Comment: sorry i'm newbie in this stackoverflow:(

Comment: Which method or constructor does it return the error message you have mentioned? Is the issue happened on `Nagivator.push` ? The methods you have passed to `ElevatedButton` seems legit but the `builder` method in `Navigator.push` is so confusing

Comment: precisely at the elevated button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with this code

```
 Container(
    //child: IndexedStack(
      //index: _selectedIndex,
      //children: _items
    //)//_items.elementAt(_index),
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.25,
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
    child: IndexedStack(
      index: _selectedIndex,
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            minimumSize: const
            Size.fromHeight(50)
          ),
          child: Text('SUBUH'),
          onPressed: (){
            Navigator.push(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => halamansubuh(
              )
              ),);}),
        
              ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  minimumSize: const
                  Size.fromHeight(100)
              ),
                child: Text('ZUHUR'),
                onPressed: (){
                  Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => halamanzuhur(title: 'halamanzuhur', desc: 'halamanzuhur',
                    
                    )
                    ));
                }
              ),
              
        ]
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigator.push needs 2 arguments. you are giving it 3. it needs a context and a route. You are giving it a 3rd arguement, the ElevatedButton. It doesn't belong there,

Maybe you want that ElevatedButton instead of the halamansubuh() ?

Comment: where can i upload the code? so you can help my code:{